# Freelancing Haram or Halal?

Tags: halal-haram

I am a graphic designer and work as a freelancer. I am earning decent amount of money which really helps me a lot.
My questions is:

Is freelancing Haram or Halal? Since your work like this is not registered somewhere and you **pay no tax** and there is no limit on the amount of money you can collect or ...!

This can be answered whether Islam allows this? and what Islam says if governments would go against it?

Comment: Why would you think it's haram?

Comment: It just came to my mind and what if someone asks me about it.

Comment: -1, really low quality question, can you add more things to show you actually did some research before asking ? :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FreeLancing is obviously not haram. You provide a service based on a pay. It is perfectly legal agreement. There is is nothing wrong about it.

As for the question, you do not pay taxes on it. This is relatively a new issues and still needs to be addressed by different nations. If a company is US based and you work for them from US, you will be required to provide your tax-id etc so you would not be under the hood. That case is really clear. It is not haram at all. But a freelancer from a different country does not fall in that category. The freelancer agency cannot trace taxes on every user in every country. It would be just too hectic and I believe there are no laws which govern such cases. In that case you probably want to show your income from your freelancing when you begin to file taxes.

A better option would be that you talk to government official and ask them how can you help charging taxes from freelancing (as in your case) . Or ask them if your income from freelancing is subject to taxes? That way the problem will be solved in an official way and you do not have to feel guilty about it.

Also if you fix this for your self and for others, it will be great service for your country!

Comment: Also; Our country has law about the workers who earn more than the limited earnings `sorry I don't know the limit` then he would have to pay taxes but in other case, he doesn't need to pay taxes.

Comment: Right if your income is above that limit, you can self declare your earnings and pay taxes on it. If you country is not bother about this situation, then you may well relax and not bother about it too much. It would be better to just raise this issue publicly and see what stances government has on it. Just an opinion.

Answer (score -1):

You think because you should not pay any taxes for your job (freelancing) must be haram. But it is not true. There is not laws in Islam are not allowed it.
If you live in an Islamic country and for freelancing as other jobs should be paid tax you must obey the law.

Answer (score -2):

If you read the terms and conditions of the reputed freelancing sites you can see that there is a condition which involve interest or riba on clients due passing over 1 year. 
Though workers don't involve with this riba or interest but everyone should agree this terms and conditions including this haram condition. So I think this is haram for a muslim.

Comment: This answer lacks evidences to support your claims. As if you work hard and get money the riba of the sites shouldn't disturb you as you've got the money due to your work not due to time or any possible way where you actually are inactive ...