# Is freelancing halal if my job contract prevents from working for any other place?

Tags: halal-haram

Currently, I have a Software development job. But I have a lot of free time which I want to spend on freelancing on Odesk/Upwork. I do not plan to work on anything that is Islamic-ally prohibited like work on movies, cartoons etc. Also, do not plan to work on company time, just on the weekends using my own resources.

I just want to earn more money in my spare time. Will what I earn through freelancing be halal-rizq for me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Freelancing Haram or Halal?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16163/freelancing-haram-or-halal)

Comment: Nope, I am asking if it is haram **because** it's violates the contract in my other job.

Comment: The intent of those clauses it to prevent people from working on two jobs during company time, and to prevent conflict of interest issues. It is not to prevent you from earning extra money.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I honestly think your comment should be posted as an answer. Very well said brother :)

Comment: Are you really violating your contract? You said it yourself. You work on weekends (outside of your working time) and you use your own resources (not the company's resources). How does that violates the contract?

Answer (score 3):

We are commanded repetitively by God and his messenger to honour our contracts and not to break them:

> Rasul-Allah (saw) was asked what type of earning was the best, to
>   which Rasul-Allah (SAW) answered, ''The work of a man's own hand, and
>   every pious sale''. [Hakim] Rasul-Allah (saw) said, ''A trustworthy
>   and an honest and truthful businessman will rise up with martyrs on
>   the Day of Resurrection.'' [Ibn Majah, Hakim] He (saw) also said, ''A
>   truthful, and trustworthy trader will rise up with the Prophets, the
>   righteous and the martyrs.'' [al-Hamim, Tirmidhi]
>
> 'O you who believe! Fulfil all your covenants'' [ 5:1]
>
> ''Fulfil (every) engagement, for (every) engagement will be enquired
>   into (on the Day of Reckoning)'' [17:34]

Therefore I would say that by going against the regulations defined within the contract you will be breaking them and by doing so you will also be going against the commands of God.

No matter what the reason may be, remember that these rules defined within your contract is something which you have agreed upon in the first place, agreeing to something and going against it by will can be a form of deception or hypocrisy.

one choice you can make is leave freelancing for the sake of God and trust in him as he will provide you with what is better:

> And whosoever puts his trust in Allâh, then He will suffice him [Surat
>   At-Talâq: 3]
>
> It was reported from the Prophet (peace be upon him) that he said:
>   "Anyone leaves something for the sake of Allah, Allah shall compensate
>   him a better one for that."

Another choice would be to consult your employer with this, although they sometimes set these rules and regulations, they tend to make exceptions when you discuss those rules with them.

Forgive me if my answer seems harsh, I am only sharing my understanding!

God knows best! May God guide us all!

Answer (score 2):

If your contract is such that it prevents you from working elsewhere, then you must keep your word and avoid working elsewhere. If you are doubtful regarding the terms of your contract, you should simply ask your employer.
If you were to violate your contract to earn money, it would be considered deceptive and as such your earnings wouldn't be pure.
If you are unhappy with the terms of your contract, then maybe you should negotiate with your employer for more flexible terms.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for a company not allowing to work in a different place can be

- You can get exhausted from work in other place and that can reflect in your productivity. For example, you may be working late night in week end and when you go to job, you will be sleeply and less productive. Software job is demanding on mind and good rest is required for good work output.
- Company do not want their ideas or code to be used outside. If you undertake some similar work like what you do in company, you may take their code or ideas in solving the work.

My suggestion is that you openly say to your employer what you plan to do. You can convince them that your freelancing would not anyway effect your day job. If they are ok with what your are doing, you can go ahead with freelancing.